# vtkImageViewer2 - changing volume data slice spacing value

Tags: java, vtk, dicom

I want to change the slice thickness of my dicom volume data. I'm using
vtkImageViewer2.

For example, the original data spacing is 2 and there are 200 slices, when I
change the  slice thickness value to 4 I have to see 100 slices.

```
Original:  1,2,3,4,5...
Modified:  1,  2,  3...
```

My code:

```
if ((modif & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {

                etat = 1;
                int nb0 = imageViewer.GetSlice() + 1;
                int nb1 = imageViewer.GetSlice() - 1;
                int totSlice = imageViewer.GetSliceMax() + 1;

                if (p1.y > p2.y) {

                   String Newligne=System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
                    cornerAnnotation.SetText(0,"Slice:" + (nb0 + 1) + "/" + totSlice+Newligne+"Zoom: "+(int)(100)+"%"+Newligne+  "C:" + windowhight + " /  W:" +windowlevel+ Newligne+"Pixel:("+xs+":"+ys+")"+Newligne+reader.GetModality()+"("+reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()[0]+"*"+reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()[1]+")"+"-Axial"+Newligne);

                    imageViewer.SetSlice(nb0);
                    scrollBar.setValue(imageViewer.GetSlice());

                } else {

                     String Newligne=System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

                    cornerAnnotation.SetText(0,"Slice:" + (nb1 + 1) + "/" + totSlice+Newligne+"Zoom: "+(int)(100)+"%"+Newligne+  "C:" + windowhight + " /  W:" +windowlevel+ Newligne+"Pixel:("+xs+":"+ys+")"+Newligne+reader.GetModality()+"("+reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()[0]+"*"+reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()[1]+")"+"-Axial"+Newligne);

                    imageViewer.SetSlice(nb1);
                    scrollBar.setValue(imageViewer.GetSlice());

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually change the slice thickness in the DICOM attributes, you likely will have to change the image position (patient) and slice location DICOM attributes as well in order to keep the image volume consistent.

If you are just trying to move slices based on a certain distance (e.g. one click = 4 mm instead of 2 mm), then keep track of the position of the slice instead of the slice number. When the position changes, then compute the new slice for the new position and update to that slice. This will allow more flexibility as well.

If you really just want to step every other slice, then why not just use nb0 = getSlice() + 2 and nb1 = getSlice() -2?